# Getting to many arguments for this function with the following formula in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

```
=IF(D6="Closed", IF(N6="T1",J6, IF(O6="T1",M6, IF(NOT(D6="Closed", IF(N6="T1",J6, IF(O6="T1", SUM(TODAY()-I6,""))))))))
```

I need to do three things here:
First, determine if d6 is "Closed" or something else.
If "Closed", then I want see if n6 = "T1" and if it is, return j6 (which is a number), but if it is not, then look to o6 (letter o)to see if it is "T1", and if it is, return m6.  If d6 is not "Closed", then I want to see if n6 = "T1" and if it is, return j6, but if it is not, then look to o6 to see if it is "T1", and if it is, calculate the difference between today() and i6, and if none of these are true, put a blank space ("").

Comment: Hi Susan, a couple screen caps with fake data showing what you are looking to accomplish might help explain things a bit better.

Comment: you are missing a `)` after the `NOT(D6="Closed"`

Comment: thank you @BradR.  When I add the ), I get a different error.  As for adding I tried adding screen captures - but it is not allowing me to enter it here.  Likely I just do not know how.  This is the first time I have used this.

Comment: Hi Susan, try adding it to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[Not sure this is showing - but it is my excel with some data that should help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVI37.png)

Answer (score 0):

To do what your text description asks for either of the following formulas will work:

```
=IF(N6="T1",J6,
 IF(AND(D6="Closed",O6="T1"),M6,
 IF(AND(D6<>"Closed",O6="T1"),SUM(TODAY()-I6),"")))
```

or

```
=IF(N6="T1",J6,
 IFS(  AND(D6="Closed",  O6="T1"),  M6,
       AND(D6<>"Closed",  O6="T1"),  SUM(TODAY()-I6),
       TRUE,  ""))
```

The first being a standard `IF()` approach and the second being an `IFS()` approach. The advantage to the `IFS()` approach would be if your conditions were more complex (or just "more"), it would be easier to lay them out for ease of maintenance than the standard `IF()` approach as each line in the formatted versions above would be "on its own" independent (except for order) of the other lines making editing or adding/deleting conditions simpler to figure.

Note:  You want to compare each path of conditions (i.e.:  regardless of how D6 turns out) for `N6="T1"`, so it should simply be the first condition in the overall `IF()`. That greatly simplifies what follows. Either way, by using the `AND()` approach, you can simplify the testing of O6. Since O6 is tested for the same thing, you could also "flip" the approach and test for `O6<>"T1` with that portion going something like this:

```
IF(O6<>"T1,  "",  IF(D6="Closed",  M6,  SUM(TODAY()-I6)  )
```

which would return test for failure, returning the `""` if so, and only if it DID equal "T1" would it test one D6 condition, giving whichever result that indicated.

The main point would be that looking for things like the controlling nature of the N6 test can lead to a greatly simplified formula. Any simplification has benefits such as faster response, though that's mostly a concern of the past, but the main benefits revolve around two big things:  ease of maintaining the formula in the future since it is easier to understand and often easier to fit new conditions into, but also, today for instance(!), making it less likely to not ever work at all because the "Why won't it?" is buried in a complex beast of a formula.

Comment: That worked, thank you so much.